# Displaying a list of images that just fill their available space in an expandable cell

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm, png

I've got a desktop GUI (VS2013, .NET 4.5.2) with a few levels of embedded grids. In one cell (which can be expanded in both dimensions using gridsplitters) I have this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Results.Info}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Results.Images}"/>
</Grid>
```

In the MVVM-Light-supported view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<object> Images
{
   get { return mImages; }
   set { Set(() => Images, ref mImages, value); }
}
```

I load up this property with a sequence of text (captions) and images created this way:

```
var img = new Image
{
   Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fullPathToPng)),
};

Images.Add(caption); 
Images.Add(img);
...repeat until all captions and images added
```

The code above produces images large enough to cause the listview to display scrollbars, although dragging gridsplitters eventually lets me see whole images.

Here's what I'd like to happen: The images shrink to fill just the available space without causing the listview to display its scrollbars, and when gridsplitters are moved giving this cell more space, the images grow to fill just the newly-available space.

I'm not married to using a ListView to hold the captions/images sequence, but I do want the solution to respect MVVM. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be simple: I just needed to disable the ListView's horizontal scrolling:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Results.Images}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
```